# Batch - Looping through text file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I'm trying to find all files older than 30 days in several directories using this command:

```
[Directory] && forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

The output is a .txt file.

The text file contains the path to the directory:
C:\Directory1
C:\Directory2
C:\Directory3 etc

I'm trying to loop through several directories using a text file but I need to provide 2 commands:
cd (to change to the directory whose files I need info on) and the actual command to get the information)

If I create a batch file entering the directory names manually I have something like this:

```
cd "C:Directory1" && forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
cd "C:Directory2" && forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
cd "C:Directory3" && forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

How do I enter the "cd" command at the beggining of the loop, then the directory which is in the txt file and the rest of the command `(forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path")`

What I have so far is:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\list.txt") do forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path %%A
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `/P` option with `FORFILES`?

Comment: The paths would be listed line by line in the txt file I'm trying to loop from.  How would I give it the path in the /P option if all the paths are in the txt file?

Comment: You are already using it in your `ECHO` command.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked better but I'm not getting the output with the files I need, the ones older than 30 days.  The output I'm getting is the same list of directories from the text file plus the ````forfiles /p @path /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path```` line.

Comment: Thanks @Squashman.  That was of a lot of help as well!  The ````"%%~A"```` fixed the whole thing!!!  Everything works as it did when I did the directory names manually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FOR` command with the `/F` option is used to read a file and it assigns each iteration of the file to the variable `%%A`.  So use the that variable with the `/P` option of the `FORFILES` command.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\list.txt") do forfiles /P "%%~A" /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```